# Setting up hypertables in TimescaleDB with multiple time-series

Tags: django, time-series, timescaledb

I am about to integrate TimescaleDB in my django project, but what’s unclear to me is how timescale groups different timestamps together to form a time-series.

Imagine I have multiple Drinks (coca-cola, lime-juice etc, fanta, water…). I can have a million drinks in my database. Each drink can have multiple time-series related to it. A time-series of consumption data over the years, a time-series of customer data over the years etc… Then imagine I also have food data with the same assumptions. I want to save all those data in a hypertable.

I can start by creating a hypertable and inject all consumption data for Coca-Cola in the year 2018. Now i also want to store customer data for Coca-Cola too, but the time-stamps will collide. I will have 2022-12-03 multiple times. Thus timescale must have a best-practice of how to group timestamps together to from a time-series. Otherwise I could only have a single time-series in a hypertable.

I see two solutions:

- I can save a foreign key or an object-id with the timestamp. E.g. 2022-01-01 and 5, whereas 5 is the id of coca cola object.
- Or I can create a meta-table which stores the meta-information about the timestamp. The meta object holds the information to which object the timestamp belongs to. E.g. in the meta model I can save the id for the coca-cola object and also other meta information (e.g. the amount of sugar during the whole year in the drink). I see the advantage of storing more meta information as important, so I’d prefer this approach.

My question though is: Is that how timescale is supposed to be used? Or is the idea to have one hypertable per drink in this case? That would surprise me because then I’d have millions of hypertables. Or will I lose performance if I design my setup as explained above? Or to put it simple: What is the best practice of grouping timestamps together to a time-series in timescale.

Thanks a bunch for the feedback

Comment: timescale supports both [wide and narrow models](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/overview/data-model-flexibility/)

Comment: Thanks for the link! Not sure if I get this correctly though: This means I could save all time-series data that I have from all different sorts of sources, belonging to all different sorts of objects into a single hypertable?

Comment: Wide vs. narrow model is not related to timescale - you can also do this in any other database. The decision to use one over the other depends on the use-case. And of course there are also limits: i.e. a table can only have a max. number of columns.

Comment: When you decide to put billions of rows into one table, you should think about performance/storage. This is where hypertables can help: e.g. use compression or partition large tables into chunks and maybe distribute the data over multiple disks/servers: [space vs. time-partitioning](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/hypertables/about-hypertables/)